# Angular : formControl.setValue(2, { emitEvent: false }) not updating value of prev when valueChanges.pipe(startWith(startValue), pairwise())

Tags: angular

common function for dispatchCurrentEvent

```
control.valueChanges.pipe(
          startWith(startValue), 
          pairwise())
          .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
            if (prev != next) {
             this.controlService.dispatchCurrentEvent({
                type,
                field,
                preValue: prev,
                value: next,
                section,
                rIndex,
          });
          if (field.rules?.length) 
              this.pvRulesService.handleRules(field, section, field?.rowIndex);
         }
    });

formgroup.get('mycontrol')?.setValue(1, { emitEvent: false });
```

not updating value of prev

```
control.valueChanges.pipe(
         startWith(startValue),
         pairwise())).subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any])
```

Want to set value of prev when `formgroup.get('mycontrol')?.setValue(1,{ emitEvent: false })`. But `emitEvent:false` not updating value of previous.

Comment: Wouldnt you need to specify the control to set the value to? formControl.get('myFormControl').setValue(1, { emitEvent: false }); More on this [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#replacing-a-form-control-value)